# Trying to plot a graph in a csv file

Tags: perl, csv, graph

```
use GD::Graph;
use GD::Graph::bars;
use GD::Graph::Data;




print "Content-disposition:attachment;filename=UsageReportChart.csv\n\n";
my $data = GD::Graph::Data->new([
    ["1st","2nd","3rd","4th","5th","6th","7th", "8th", "9th"],
    [    1,    2,    5,    6,    3,  1.5,    1,     3,     4],
]) or die GD::Graph::Data->error;

my $graph = GD::Graph::bars->new();

 $graph->set(
     x_label         => 'X Label',
     y_label         => 'Y label',
     title           => 'A Simple Bar Chart',

     ) or die $graph->error;
$graph->plot($data) or die $graph->error;
```

Trying to plot a graph in a csv file using this code and not getting anything in the csv file I download.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Including an image in a CSV file doesn't make any sense. CSV = comma-separated values. It's just plain text.

Comment: Reading from csv and plotting a graph in another csv file. How can I do that?

Comment: Else how to plot a graph in a png file

Comment: I'm not sure how else to say this so that it makes sense. CSV files are plain text. Images/plots/graphs are not. Aside from quoting rules, the format for CSV isn't much more complicated than newlines and commas. There's no provision for embedding images.

Comment: I am guessing [this is also you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45153099/100754). While, in theory, you could save a PNG image in a field in a CSV file, I hope no one does that.

Comment: Here is a bit from a `.png` file, copied from an editor that "opened" it: `^@^@^MIHDR^@^@^C^S^@^`.  See? It's nonsense.  And here is a line from a `.csv` file:  `one, two, three\n`.  _You cannot have a "png" anything in a plain-text file, like `.csv` is_.

Comment: @zdim See [binary option in `Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#binary). One could also uuencode or Base64 encode the binary data. I can imagine use cases for such things. **BUT** I think the OP thinks he can create something which users can open in Excel, and it will show a nice chart embedded in the spreadsheet. To do that, one would have to create an actual [Excel workbook with a chart](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel#add_chart(%25properties)).

Comment: @SinanÜnür  Right, all good points -- thank you.  I just couldn't help thinking that they want to simply put a png image in a "csv file."  But it does seem that they are rather thinking of an Excel "operated" file, which will have a chart in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in the comments, printing a graph (which is an image) into a CSV file is a terrible idea.

But your code for creating a graph seems like it's pretty close. You just need to take a closer look at [the bits of the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD::Graph) that cover outputting the final image.

You call the `plot()` method, but there's more to do after that. The `plot()` method returns a [GD::Image](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD::Image) object and you need to call another method on that object (`gif()`, `png()` or something like that) to get the image. You then need to do something with that data (probably print it somewhere).

This code prints your graph to STDOUT. In a CGI program, that will send the graph image back to the browser. The `Content-type` header gives the browser enough information to display that image.

```
my $img = $graph->plot($data);

# This assumes you haven't already printed a header
# so remove the incorrect one from above in your code
print "Content-type: image/png\n\n";

print $img->png;
```